# is there a log in my android of GPS & speed? Asking after car accident 2 weeks ago

Tags: gps, geolocation, gps-tracking

I was in an auto accident two weeks ago, and the onboard dashcam had failed to record anything.  But, I had two Android phones on (both with GPS / location enabled, one on Android 9 (LG V35 Thinq), one on Android 11 (Pixel 4)).

Is there a log in the phone for the past n days of location and speed (and perhaps direction)?

(I was not running any particular GPS tracking/logging app, probably had phone, messaging, Pokemon Go, and Facebook in the "background".)

The information might help avoid my insurance rates going sky high :)

thanks!

Comment: check google maps timeline